# Setting the value of select dropdown using angular and selectboxit

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, selectboxit

I am using the jquery plugin "selectboxit" for my dropdown. Below is the html code with the angular directive "image-select-box" that initializes the select drop down to selectboxit.

```
<select ng-model="line" class="form-control" id="line" value="line"  image-select-box >
   <option value="0" data-iconurl="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAHgAAAAPCAYAAAAvQwurAAAAWUlEQVRYR+3WwQkAIRAEQc0/aAVfghmUfRn0lAs3Rx+9wKTrihsB448g4IDxBfC8LjhgfAE8777ghbf+lndsA3bZH2A39eOyfrJw/IADxhfA87rggPEF8LwNEroCEIoaIokAAAAASUVORK5CYII="></option>
   <option value="1" ng-selected='{{line == "1"}}' data-iconurl="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAHgAAAAPCAYAAAAvQwurAAAAc0lEQVRYR+2VSQ4AIAwC2/8/Wq9q4g0NIeMDsDBdunjRCXS0O8wVgMObAMAADk8g3B4TDODwBMLtrRM8xF7P7YD+HvCXfAB87+ovAJbvnwwAN1i8ttzkAOxGRFwPgMWBuskB2I2IuB4AiwN1kwOwGxFxPRP1UgoQsxww9AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="></option>
   <option value="2" data-iconurl="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAHgAAAAPCAYAAAAvQwurAAAAcElEQVRYR+2WQQ4AEBAD+f+jSZyExG1bacYDVGeW6I0VTaBHt6NcQ3D4ECAYweEEwutxgxEcTiC83n6Dx+ddz9eG876FLV4Irptq90BeguuqsrONAJ8sG3pNMII1nG0pCLah1wQjWMPZloJgG3pN8AQkBgYQvlQpRwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="></option>
   <option value="3" data-iconurl="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAHgAAAAPCAYAAAAvQwurAAAAZklEQVRYR+2XuxUAIAjEYP+htdDCzwSEWFqZi4fPDBc6gUTTCRcKhl8CBSsYngAczwYrGJ4AHO9s8Nisb6vdX8GUzEHB8f0kSoo8BtF1ft/gRiMajtoTzwbDvStYwfAE4Hg2GC54AkdIKBCb7coGAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"></option>
```

The content of the link function in directive is as follows

```
var $targetSelects = $(element),
      selectConfig = {
      autoWidth: false
};
$targetSelects.selectBoxIt(selectConfig);
$targetSelects.selectBoxIt('refresh');
```

The issue that I am having is that the selected value is not getting updated using ng-select.

If I hardcode selected ="selected" at any of the options, it shows the selected value properly. However, if I use ng-selected to set the selected attribute I notice that during the link function, all the ng-selected attributes compute to false and that's why selectboxit, doesn't show the actual selected option. However, after the page has loaded, I see that ng-selected has added the selected attribute to the proper option element.

This essentially means that the custom attribute is getting compiled and linked before the ng-selected attribute has compiled and linked.

I have set the priority of the custom attribute to 1000 but still am unable to get it work.

Any help will be appreciated.